# Interpolate path to remove diagonal movements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame containing XY coordinates of a path that moves either 1 unit up/down, 1 unit left/right, or 1 unit up/down **AND** 1 unit left/right.

```
    X   Y
0   -23.0   -70.0
6   -24.0   -70.0
8   -24.0   -69.0
18  -25.0   -68.0
27  -25.0   -67.0
29  -26.0   -67.0
37  -26.0   -66.0
45  -27.0   -66.0
...
```

Computing distances between consecutive points using `np.sum(np.abs(df.diff()), axis=1)`, diagonal movements are found where the distance is equal to 2 units.

```
0     0.0
6     1.0
8     1.0
18    2.0
27    1.0
29    1.0
37    1.0
45    1.0
...
dtype: float64
```

My problem is, I want the path to move only 1 unit up/down or 1 unit left/right, but not both at the same time. Below is my current solution where I insert an 'in between' row in points where the distance is 2 units. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

```
def manhattanize(df):
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import itertools
    dists = list(np.sum(np.abs(df.diff()), axis=1))
    coords = df.to_numpy()
    def fill_gaps(i):
        dist = dists[i]
        current_coord = coords[i]
        if dist == 2:
            prev_coord = coords[i-1]
            in_between = prev_coord[0], current_coord[1]
            return [in_between, current_coord]
        else:
            return [current_coord]

    n = len(df.index)
    coords = [fill_gaps(i) for i in range(n)]
    coords = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(coords))
    df = pd.DataFrame(coords, columns=['X','Y'])
    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to clean up the index:

```
>>> df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df
      X     Y
0 -23.0 -70.0
1 -24.0 -70.0
2 -24.0 -69.0
3 -25.0 -68.0
4 -25.0 -67.0
5 -26.0 -67.0
6 -26.0 -66.0
7 -27.0 -66.0
```

Now we let all the even indices be the original coordinates, but the odd indices
will take the X coordinate of the *next* element.

```
even_indices = 2 * np.arange(len(df))
even = df.set_index(even_indices)
odd = df.set_index(1 + even_indices)
odd["X"][:-1] = df["X"][1:]
```

Finally, we merge these two, **drop the duplicates**, and clean up our index again:

```
df = pd.concat([even, odd]).sort_index()
df = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

The final result:

```
      X     Y
0 -23.0 -70.0
1 -24.0 -70.0
2 -24.0 -69.0
3 -25.0 -69.0
4 -25.0 -68.0
5 -25.0 -67.0
6 -26.0 -67.0
7 -26.0 -66.0
8 -27.0 -66.0
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to change the drop duplicates line to `df = df.loc[(df.shift() != df).any(axis=1)]`.